# Why am I getting "Permission denied" when trying to get the file path to a txt file?

Tags: python, bash, text

I'm trying to exchange a string between a Python file and a Shell script. Here is how I'm doing it:

```
#! /bin/bash

# This gets the file location of the script:
SCRIPT=$(readlink -f "$0")
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

TEXT=$("$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt")

ENTRY_VAR=$(zenity --entry --text="$TEXT")

echo "$ENTRY_VAR" > "$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt"
```

I'm writing to the text file from the Python script, but on line 7 of the shell script (`TEXT=$("$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt")`) I get the error code:

```
/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/ZenityPy/ZenityFiles/entry.sh: line 7: /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/ZenityPy/ZenityFiles/text.txt: Permission denied
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TEXT=$("$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt")` means "execute the *command* called `"$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt"` and store its stdout in `TEXT`.  You get the "permission denied" error because that file is not executable.

Instead you probably want `TEXT=$(cat "$SCRIPTPATH/text.txt")`.